# catching exceptions in asp.net markup

Tags: asp.net, exception, markup

How does one go about catching exceptions from using controls in markup?

For example, I have the following code

```
<asp:XmlDataSource ID="XmlDataSource1" 
                   runat="server" 
                   DataFile="http://feeds.feedburner.com/"
                   XPath="rss/channel/item [position()<=10]"></asp:XmlDataSource>
```

If feedburner is down for whatever reason, where does the exception get thrown too and how do I catch this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would probably resort to setting the properties in code behind and handling the data binding manually within a try/catch block.  This would allow you to eat the exception and put up some sort of error message.

Answer (score 1):

You could always let it fall through to `Application_Error` in Global.asax.cs, if you have any kind of global error handling in place.